# Filtering NSDictionary entries based on NSArray Selection

Tags: objective-c

I have a NSDictionary that holds information about memories in my radio. The memories are arranged in banks labelled "A" through the "E". My NSDictionary has 5 entries with the 'key' for each being the bank label ("A", "B" etc). The 'value' is an array containing instances of a class with all of the information about that memory.

I also have a separate NSArray that just holds the labels to the banks, "A", B" etc.

Both the NSDictionary and NSArray are properties in my class that can be accessed from a form.

On my form I have a NSArrayController bound to the NSArray which is in turn bound to an NSPopupButton to select the "bank" I want to address. This works well and I can see the string holding the bank name change as I select different entries.

The form also has an NSDictionaryController that is bound to the NSDictionary. My intent is to select the "bank" via its NSPopupButton and then filter the NSDictionaryController to display only the entries in the NSArray that is the corresponding 'value' to the selected bank key.

(I hope this makes sense!)

However I'm stuck as to how to fill in the bindings fields to filter the NSDictionaryController based on the currently selected value of the NSArrayController.

Any pointers and suggestions would be welcomed.

Susan

Answer (score 0):

No need for a `NSDictionaryController`. Just bind another `NSArrayController` to a property in your controller, say `bankObjects`. And assuming your banks dictionary is called `banks` and you have a string named `selectedBankName` that is set by your popup in a KVO compliant manner, you can implement `bankObjects` like so:

```
- (NSArray *)bankObjects {

    return  banks[selectedBankName];
}
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingBankObjects {

    return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"selectedBankName",nil];
}
```

The second method automatically signals that when `selectedBankName` changes, `bankObjects` change as well. And the first method returns `bankObjects` based on the `selectedBankName`.